# VBS Calculator issues

Tags: vbscript

In this calculator program, the `+` works but `-`, `*` and `/` do not work. Why?

```
Option Explicit
Dim IB, Sum1, Sum2, Sym
Sum1 = InputBox("Enter first #NO", "VBS Calculator")
If Not IsNumeric(IB) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid Number"
ElseIf IsNumeric(IB) Then
    If Not IsNumeric(IB) Then
        MsgBox " Please enter a valid Number"
    ElseIf IsNumeric(IB) Then
        Sum2 = InputBox("Enter second #NO", "VBS Calculator")
        Sym = InputBox("Enter a law of Arithmetic", "VBS Calculator")
        If Sym = "+" Then MsgBox (CInt(Sum1) + CInt(Sum2))
    ElseIf Sym = "-" Then MsgBox (CInt(Sum1) - CInt(Sum2))
    ElseIf Sym = "/" Then MsgBox (CInt(Sum1) / CInt(Sum2))
    ElseIf Sym = "*" Then MsgBox (CInt(Sum1) * CInt(Sum2))
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Properly indenting your code reveals the mistake instantly. I did this for you — have a look.

Comment: Solved? While checking Empty IB with IsNumeric()? And still no ops except +?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Somebody already mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the statement on the same line as the `if then` then any else clauses have no effect.
e.g.

```
if a=b then statement
```

is the logical equivalent of

```
if a = b then
    statement
end if
```

Your code has other issues too, like checking for `Elseif IsNumeric(IB) then` followed by `if Not IsNumeric(IB) then`  The second if will always be skipped, going straight to the elseif

Comment: @Mindrus Consider using a [Select Case](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_conditionals.asp) which might help with the your `else if`'s